# How to remove lines of csv files under conditions using awk?

Tags: linux, awk

I got file.csv with 3 columns looks like this:

```
"/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd",-112.263,1
"001aCqAT2O+SbZfeC7UmhQ",,0
"/001DLIWmCvBwVCJrQjiQA",310,0
"fasdDLIWmCvBwVCJrQjiQA",0,0
...
```

but some of lines have no column 2 value or 0 column 2 value I would like to delete those lines to get:

```
"/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd",-112.263,1
"/001DLIWmCvBwVCJrQjiQA",310,0
...
```

How can I do this using awk in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read question wrong

In awk to remove line

```
awk -F, 'NF!=3' file
```

Actually this is better

```
awk -F, '$2' file
```

Incase $2 can be 0

```
awk -F, '$2!=""' file
awk -F, '$2~/./' file
```

Comment: I like the second solution, which I would also have used (although not as concise). The first solution works but does **not** solve the OPs problem (but a similar one that leads to the same output).

Comment: @martin I noticed that it may not solve it which is why i added the second, just thought id leave it incase someone found it useful :)

Comment: @martin the second is **wrong answer**!  it looks compact and nice, but OP didn't tell that `$s` will always be non-zero value. what about `"foo",0,1`? the line will be cut out, which is wrong.

Comment: @Kent i just noticed that i had edited just before i saw your comment :)

Comment: @kent I changed it again ha :)

Comment: Sorry guys!!I wrote the wrong question every line should contain 3 columns! And the value of second column may be empty and this is when I want to remove the line. Could you edit the answer sorry again!

Answer (score 1):

why not think about using **grep**?

```
grep -v '^[^,],,'  file
```

Comment: Thank you so much do you know how to use awk to convert lines like /cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd,-112.263 to "/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd",-112.263? add the double quote?

Comment: @user3692521 try `awk -F, -v q='"' '{$1=q$1q}7' file`

Comment: @kent that will print without the commas

Comment: What if to convert the first two columns? /cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd,dfadsfadsfasdf,-112.263 to "/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd","dfadsfadsfasdf",-112.263

Comment: `awk -F, -v q='"' '{$1=q$1q;$2=q$2q}7' file`

Comment: `awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=N;i++) $i="\""$i"\""}1' OFS="," file` change N for however many fields you want to quote

Comment: @user3692521 yes, I forgot the `OFS`, you need add `-v OFS=","` after `-F,` to have CSV format in output.

Comment: Sorry guys!!I wrote the wrong question every line should contain 3 columns! And the value of second column may be empty and this is when I want to remove the line. Could you edit the answer sorry again!

Comment: @user3692521 could your column2 contain an empty string? if in this case, do you want to have it in output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk '/",,/{next}{print}' file
"/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd",-112.263
"/001DLIWmCvBwVCJrQjiQA",310
```

OR

```
$ awk -F, 'NF>2{next;}{print}' file
"/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd",-112.263
"/001DLIWmCvBwVCJrQjiQA",310
```

OR

```
$ awk -F, 'NF<3' file
"/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd",-112.263
"/001DLIWmCvBwVCJrQjiQA",310
```

Comment: While they all do provide the output the poster wants, they do **not** solve the problem of deleting rows that have a second field empty (in the strict sense).

Comment: you mean this `awk -F, '$2==""{next}{print}' file`

Comment: Actually, yes. I didn't want to be harsh, I just realized that.